# Fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV error after setting background image

Tags: android, android-activity, segmentation-fault

I am trying to set display_jobs_page activitie's background image using PNG file but getting this error while trying to open this activity from another activity with basic code

```
public void openJobsPage (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayJobsPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I tried using blank background and it opens, tried other images in my resource folder and it works too. I am putting images in drawable-hdpi folder. I am sure that problem is with the file But this file doesn't differ from other files, basicly same size and same dimensions 2648x 1601.

Tried looking into settings how much this app uses of system memory and getting only 2MB

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: A segfault is an exception in native code. You have probably found a bug with the png reader (and there is probably some kind of unusual or wrong data in that png) `2648x 1601` is also quite big (requires ~ 16MiB of RAM).

Comment: changed resolution for a bit 2118x1281 and it was fine. It opened quickly